# When any browser saves a file on android, is there a broadcast sent? How can I intercept saved/downloaded files in a browser on Android?

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent

I want to create an application where users can choose to *save* a file into my application and go through an activity to do so.

I'm brand new to Android programming, but I've been a Java developer for quite a while. After reading some of the documentation I've seen that the way I'd probably go about this is via a Broadcast Receiver, or something involving intents.

The exact thing I'd like to see on the phone:

- Users holds finger down on image in the browser
- User chooses to download (or some other choice as created by my application)
- My application is presented as a *destination* or *handler* for this content, as when I attempt to take a photo it will ask me if I would like to use Camera or Snapchat. I assume this would be done by handling the intent.

I'm curious as to exactly how I would achieve this.

Comment: What specific browser are you referring to? Are you writing this browser? What specific image are you referring to? Are you writing the Web page that hosts this image?

Comment: It would have to be browser and domain independent.  I'm writing an application to manage the downloaded images. I have no control over how the user browses the web nor the images the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Users holds finger down on image in the browser
> - User chooses to download (or some other choice as created by my application)

You are welcome to write your own Web browser, where you control what happens when the user long-presses on an image. The authors of other Web browsers will control what happens when the user long-presses on an image in their apps.

Some Web browser developers might offer a "share image" option when the user long-presses on an image. For those that do, you can be an option for handling that "share" request by implementing an activity that supports `ACTION_SEND` for whatever MIME types that you support.

Some Web browser developers might offer a "save image" or "view image" or "open image in another app" option when the user long-presses on an image. If they do, depending on where and how they do this, it is likely that the user might be able to choose to view the image (e.g., once it is "saved"). You can be an option for viewing images by implementing an activity that supports `ACTION_VIEW` for whatever MIME types that you support.

However, please bear in mind that neither of these are exclusive to Web browsers. You will be an option for any matching `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_VIEW` request, whether it is triggered by a long-press of an image in a Web browser or anything else.